# How to load modal after form post which is present inside modal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal which is triggered using a button
**Button**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="issueBookBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#issueBookModal">Issue Book</button>
```

**Modal**

```
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header bg-theme03">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Issue Book</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("IssueBookToMember", "Library", new { libraryid = LibraryId }, FormMethod.Post, null))
        {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <hr />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @if (ViewBag.Success != null)
                        {
                            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 text-center successMessageDiv" id="successDiv">
                                <label id="settingSuccessMessageId"> @ViewBag.Success</label>
                            </div>
                        }
                        @if (ViewBag.Error != null)
                        {
                            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 text-center errorMessageDiv" id="errorDiv">
                                <label id="settingSuccessMessageId"> @ViewBag.Error</label>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row bg-info" style="padding:20px; margin:20px">
                                <div class="form-horizontal col-sm-6" style="padding:20px">
                                    <div class="form-group ">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ISBN, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                                        <div class="col-md-9">
                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ISBN, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ISBN, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group ">
                                        @Html.Label("Book Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                                        <div class="col-md-9">
                                            <input type="text" id="BookNameId" readonly class="form-control">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group ">
                                        @Html.Label("ISBNs", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                                        <div class="col-md-9">
                                            <input type="text" id="ISBNId" readonly class="form-control">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group ">
                                        @Html.Label("Authors", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                                        <div class="col-md-9">
                                            <input type="text" id="AuthorsId" readonly class="form-control">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-horizontal col-sm-6 verticalLine" style="padding:20px">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.memberUserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                                        <div class="col-md-9">
                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.memberUserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Search member by Username" } })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.memberUserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group ">
                                        @Html.Label("Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                                        <div class="col-md-9">
                                            <input type="text" id="NameId" readonly class="form-control">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group ">
                                        @Html.Label("Email ID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                                        <div class="col-md-9">
                                            <input type="text" id="EmailId" readonly class="form-control">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group ">
                                        @Html.Label("Contact No", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                                        <div class="col-md-9">
                                            <input type="text" id="ContactId" readonly class="form-control">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IssueDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IssueDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IssueDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReturnDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReturnDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReturnDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="button" id="verifyISBNBtn" value="Verify Book By ISBN" class="btn btn-warning pull-left" />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**POST Action method**

```
         [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult IssueBookToMember(Guid libraryId, LibraryBookIssueForm form)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (DBContext dBContext = new DBContext())
            {
                //check Book is present in library
                var checkbook = DBContext.Books.Any(f => f.Book_ISBN == form.ISBN || f.Book_ISBN13 == form.ISBN);

                if (checkbook)
                {
                    //Code to issue book to member

                    //Code ends
                    ViewBag.Success = "Book was successfully issued.";
                    ModelState.Clear();
                    form = new LibraryBookIssueForm();
                    return View();
                }
                else
                {
                    //Don't have permission
                    ViewBag.Error = "Book does not exists.";
                    ModelState.Clear();
                    form = new LibraryBookIssueForm();
                    return View(form);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Error = "Please provide valid information";
            return View(form);
        }
    }
```

**Issue**
when i am posting the form inside modal it's hits action method and every things works fine except page gets reloaded and message does not show up in modal which i have passed using ViewBag (ViewBag.Success or ViewBag.Error) because modal has to be triggered to make it visible.

Is there any way to achieve it or i have to use Ajax form submit.
**Any suggestions**

Comment: `@Html.BeginForm()` makes a normal submit. If you want to stay on the same page, then male an ajax call (using either `@Ajax.BeginForm()`, or better using `$.ajax()`). But you seem to be returning the same view, so why return it at all - its already in the view - you should be just returning a `JsonResult` indicating success or otherwise

Comment: You could do that if you are using an i frame.

Comment: @GiovanniRomio i think returning JsonResult will be better approach.Thanks for idea although.